# Can I use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() inside content scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() inside content scripts, but it is not working! How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: what's "content script"? be more descriptive. you may wanna read the [FAQ entry on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). welcome aboard, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, Eliran, but I find this question clear enuogh.  "Content scripts" are main components in Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In [this documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) it says that a content script **cannot**

> Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)

Also it says that

> Content scripts can indirectly use the chrome.* APIs
>
> by exchanging messages with their parent extension

How to indirectly use chrome.* APIs can be learned by taking a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4M_a7xejYI&feature=player_embedded). Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Can't Tell, I think you mean "a content script cannot" instead of "a background page cannot".  If so, please edit it.